# Node - Not able to catch error thrown in callback function

Tags: node.js, error-handling, callback

I have the please of working with a callback function which throws an error when I callback an error to it, it kind of looks like the following where the `barCallback` is a 3rd-party package I cannot edit:

```js
var barCallback = function(data) {
  if (data === 'error') {
  throw Error('this is an error');
  }
};

var foo = function(callback) {
  callback('error', null);
};

foo(barCallback).then(console.log('Success')).catch('Failure!');
```

And I get:

```
    throw Error('this is an error');
    ^

Error: this is an error
```

If I instead throw the error with a throw instead of a callback I get the same but

How do I catch the error? I have tried try-catch but that won't work for callback functions.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue now with a callback and throwing an error object.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Promise` methods on a synchronous function, this is why it does not work. Also the argument for `.then()` and `.catch()` should be a function, not an expression. This is the code that does what you expect:

```js
var barCallback = function (data) {
  if (data === 'error') {
    throw Error('this is an error');
  }
};

var foo = async function (callback) {
  return callback('error', null);
};

foo(barCallback)
  .then(() => console.log('Success'))
  .catch(() => console.log('Failure!'));
```

Note that `foo` is now an `async` function - so that it returns a `Promise` - so that you can call `.then()` and `.catch()` on it in the main function.
Also note that arguments to `then()` and `catch()` are functions.